# ARM GNU Compiler -j[jobs] option exist

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, arm, gnu

I cannot find an option for the ARM GNU toolchain to compile multiple c files at the same time.  I use make -j5 all the time when compiling using gcc.  Helps speed up compile time dramatically.  Be nice if ARM GNU had a similar option.

Here is my setup:
--Fedora 20
--Core i5
--Eclipse with ARM GNU plugin
--ARM GNU 4.8-2014-q1-update (from here: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)
--Target uP: STM32F205RB

I've tried to get CodeSourcery GCC working, unsuccessfully.  ARM GNU seemed to work well after little setup.  CodeSourcery GCC should have a -j option, as we cross compile all the time for embedded linux.

Comment: Take care compiling toolchains using the `-j` option. They may have non intuitive dependencies with the several packages!

Comment: Uh? make and the compiler are 2 orthogonal concepts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is not multi-threaded. The `-j<n>` switch is specific to `make` build system, not the compiler. It tells `make` how many tasks it can run in parallel.

If you run `make -j4` you can observe in your task manager/top/process list that it tries to run 4 instances of GCC compiling 4 independent `*.c` files at the same time.

To make use of `-j` command you must have a `Makefile` in your project that can benefit from it. It should have multiple independent targets, so that they can be launched in parallel.

If you are lost in the terminology, I advice you to look at `make` tutorial, such as this one:
http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

The usual strategy here is to have a separate target for every `c` or `cpp` file in our project. That way make can easily spawn multiple compiler processes for each compilation unit. Once all *.o files are generated, they are linked.

Let's see at this example snippet:

```
SRCS  := main.c func.c other.c another_file.c ...
OBJS  := $(SRCS:.c=.o)

objects: $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
  gcc -o $(@) -c $(<)
```

We pass a list of `c` files, change them to corresponding `o` file using suffix substitution and treat the list of `*.o` files as targets. Now the `make` can compile each `c` file in parallel.

In contrast, if we do something like this:

```
SRCS  := main.c func.c other.c another_file.c ...

all:
  gcc $(SRCS) -o a.out
```

...we won't benefit from `-j` switch at all, because there is only one target.

Comment: Thanks!  I was just about to post saying I'm dumb as it's the make system not gcc

Comment: For anyone who is trying to do this in eclipse, follow these step:
1. Goto: Project->Properties->c/c++ Build->Builder Settings
2. uncheck use default build command
3. Append -j5 to Build Command( or -jX, X usually is # cores you have  +1)

This will usually work if your make supports threaded compile.  On my platter drive machine, it didn't make much of a difference, but on my SSD machine, it compiled in 1/3 the time.